# Pandas: Data Frame has 2 columns as 1

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

```
q.head()
```

Outputs

```
                Weekly_Sales
Date                    
2010-02-28     131963.08
2010-03-31      91237.14
2010-04-30     150516.76
2010-05-31      66694.15
2010-06-30      66740.70
```

Now the problem i'm facing is that i want to plot 'Date' Column vs 'Weekly_Sales' Column. I've already used the command

```
q=y.resample('M',on='Date').sum()
```

to convert weekly data to monthly which results in the upper Dataframe.

```
type(q)
```

outputs "class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'" showing that q is a data frame. Now since q doesn't have two different columns as shown here,

```
q.Weekly_Sales
```

outputs

```
Date
2010-02-28    131963.08
2010-03-31     91237.14
2010-04-30    150516.76
2010-05-31     66694.15
2010-06-30     66740.70
2010-07-31     81915.01
2010-08-31     64578.81
2010-09-30     71913.27
2010-10-31    134644.53
2010-11-30     92161.40
2010-12-31    173983.88
2011-01-31     69146.59
2011-02-28    125762.63
2011-03-31     82823.34
2011-04-30    165056.95
2011-05-31     68251.72
2011-06-30     62978.57
2011-07-31     78856.23
2011-08-31     59061.95
2011-09-30     87756.41
2011-10-31     98806.83
2011-11-30     98537.51
2011-12-31    174512.07
2012-01-31     70205.35
2012-02-29    134683.30
2012-03-31    114680.54
2012-04-30    125600.12
2012-05-31     70792.98
2012-06-30     83646.54
2012-07-31     66468.79
2012-08-31     83045.57
2012-09-30     76137.90
2012-10-31     96244.56
Freq: M, Name: Weekly_Sales, dtype: float64
```

whereas

```
q.Date
```

outputs

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#8>", line 1, in <module>
    q.Date
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 3614, in __getattr__
    return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'Date'
```

since both the columns come under q.Weekly_Sales , how do i seperate them to get 2 columns and finally plot them?

Comment: `q[['Weekly_Sales']].reset_index()`

Comment: @Wen I used that command, since i'm new to pandas, it looks like that didn't do anything. How can i check if it did?

Comment: new_s=q[['Weekly_Sales']].reset_index() assign it back

Comment: Perfect. Assigning it back Works and returns 2 columns. Thanks a lot

Comment: @Wen I think you should post as an answer for future references/visits :)

Comment: @RafaelC ok doing it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

double `[[]]` will query the single columns as dataframe rather than Series, then we using `reset_index`

```
new_s=q[['Weekly_Sales']].reset_index()
```